oc mirror failed to mirror images into JFrog registry
Not able to do oc mirror for RHOCP registry into JFrog Artifactory.
Below is error log...
=== Error Log ===
error: unable to push quay.io/openshift-release-dev/ocp-v4.0-art-dev: failed to upload blob sha256:6be5e07535c757739eef07cb562e3576cfef9ffba818e39a8c87dce32fd9210f: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:ed8480e111262fe1cbbc9c4b9c28f86ded7b535b9a032f6465d24cddb1beafe7 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:1d486fbe97683bbcf5ab9312175986961bacdd081debecfce90ba640dc9d639d to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:9986ec7c9024f2c9de21376cb6548120aa6150ea295fd96c8b6ff483a09d82ef to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:d33da5f7f040f0170507ca8e274262cf87b60c7f5e7f35e4a436d1274e844dc0 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:6b7d7bd078ef3dfa93580229cb75bbb0eb46204ffcd4f63e7ab2e4569f1ba773 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:0dfb7f24de4fa2eb127ff942bcd0d465ae69a09bcc9ff50cb1b72cbd916c4ac4 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:800528c3afb9ae1f42c819e13a16727ceda48cad6df9f45631fd36570cdcb34f to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:3a058931b2d00ea5bd5b9835ff6c760892a97c9ab5fa6219da6f5716b7e5e92d to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:6e0466107529c59294a6ed04bd6f6cd1b9143df1f31f1066a85bbb14ed18c7b8 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:36216fbd759f5ac38e2a80435d40a2265711f826ac40b8f5f3a9c7c3be26e823 to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
error: unable to upload blob sha256:cb14fca223e6c3770f2ba33987e390a0ce469a6781d071efa8387f244de345df to jfrog.eywa.lab:443/ocp413: unknown: Not Found
info: Mirroring completed in 1m24.44s (0B/s)
error: one or more errors occurred while uploading images

=== End Of Log ===
Thank You
Oc Mirror to get completed. It work easily with QUAY!!!
